# Firebase Cloud Messaging - ошибка, которую мне не понять

Tags: java

Собираю свое приложение на основе сэмплов от FCM. Настроил свой проект должным образом, но ругается на одну лишь строку:

```
    package com.example.platoon.ktv.java;

    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.example.platoon.ktv.R;
    import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.FirebaseJobDispatcher;
    import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayDriver;
    import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

                if (true) {
                    scheduleJob();
                } else {
                    handleNow();
                }

            }

            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNewToken(String token) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
        }

        private void scheduleJob() {
            FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
            Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    .setService(MyJobService.class)
                    .setTag("my-job-tag")
                    .build();
            dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
        }

        private void handleNow() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
        }

        private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
            // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
        }

        private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                            .setContentText(messageBody)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                        "Channel human readable title",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

А именно на

```
    .setService(MyJobService.class)

    setService
    (java.lang.Class<? extends com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService>)
    in Builder cannot be applied
    to
    (java.lang.Class<com.example.platoon.ktv.java.MyJobService>)
```

Чувствую, что ответ рядом, но где - не могу понять. Help (

Comment: попробуйте добавить - import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService;

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло, [вот скриншот](https://i.imgur.com/ghr46TM.png)